# SwiftData : Undo Action on a Specific Item

Tags: swift, swift-data

I'm creating a reminder app and I want to be able to undo an action a specific reminder.

Reminders are linked of a specific model `ReminderItem`, with a relationship to another model `ReminderRecurrenceItem`.

The app is split in 3 parts :

#### 1 - The main view, where I call my modelContainer

```
import SwiftData

@main
struct RemindrApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            RemindersView()
                .modelContainer(for: [ReminderRecurrenceItem.self, ReminderItem.self], isUndoEnabled: true)
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2 - The reminder component

```
struct Reminder: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    let reminderItem: ReminderItem
    let undoManager = UndoManager()
    @State private var isDone = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing:16) {
            // Component UI Code
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            if !isDone {
                // Update the component
            }
        }
        .overlay{
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Menu {
                        Button {
                            context.undoManager?.undo()
                        } label: {
                            Label("Undo action", systemImage: "arrow.uturn.backward.circle")
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### 3 - A view to display all the Reminder Items

```
struct RemindersView: View {
    
    @Query private var reminderItems: [ReminderItem]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            if reminderItems.isEmpty {
                // Empty State
            } else {
                    VStack (spacing: 24) {
                        LazyVGrid(columns: [.init(.adaptive(minimum: 150, maximum: .infinity), spacing: 16)], spacing: 16) {
                            ForEach(reminderItems) { reminderItem in
                                Reminder(reminderItem: reminderItem)
                                    .onChange(of: reminderItem.endDate, {
                                        //Do things
                                    })
                                    .onChange(of: reminderItem.isDone, {
                                        //Do things
                                    })
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FYI: I hardly simplify my code

So, when do some actions on one reminder, then undo actions from the another, it's the last action done that is undone, not the last one related to the item:

[Gif of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIDXa.gif)

I tried all what I could find on the internet related to modelContext and UndoManager, but nothing was conclusive.

Comment: Your code is far from reproducible but if you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/undomanager) for the UndoManager you will see that you need to register an (or many) undo operation for your target. So if you do that correctly you should be able to connect the undo button/action to the correct model object. Another, easier, option is to try to use the environment undo manager, `@Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager`, and see if that behaves more correct for your use case.